# Disable swiping multi items on SwipeDelegate

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

By default SwipeDelegate allows for swiping multi items like below image:

[image]

As you can see, multi swipe items are open at a time and i want only one open item at a time, means if you open item #1, by opening item #2, item #1 should close. how can i achieve this?

Sample code for a ListView with SwipeDelegate:

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent

    delegate: SwipeDelegate {
        id: delegate

        text: modelData
        width: parent.width

        swipe.right: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height

            Label {
                text: qsTr("SOME ACTION BUTTON")

                padding: 20
                anchors.fill: parent
            }

        }
    }

    model: ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement { text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
        ListElement { text: "Curabitur sit amet risus" }
        ListElement { text: "Suspendisse vehicula nisi" }
        ListElement { text: "Mauris imperdiet libero" }
        ListElement { text: "Sed vitae dui aliquet augue" }
        ListElement { text: "Praesent in elit eu nulla" }
        ListElement { text: "Etiam vitae magna" }
        ListElement { text: "Pellentesque eget elit euismod" }
        ListElement { text: "Nulla at enim porta" }
        ListElement { text: "Fusce tincidunt odio" }
        ListElement { text: "Ut non ex a ligula molestie" }
        ListElement { text: "Nam vitae justo scelerisque" }
        ListElement { text: "Vestibulum pulvinar tellus" }
        ListElement { text: "Quisque dignissim leo sed gravida" }
    }


    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
}
```

Comment: Code please. [**help/MCVE**](/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]

Comment: @derM  I add a sample code, the code is a minified version of [this official example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-swipetoremove-example.html)

Comment: @EligijusPupeikis I add a example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent

        ButtonGroup {
            buttons: listView.contentItem.children
        }

        delegate: SwipeDelegate {
            id: delegate

            checkable: true
            text: modelData
            width: parent.width
            checked: swipe.complete
            onCheckedChanged: if (!checked) swipe.close()

            swipe.right: Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "#666"

                Label {
                    text: qsTr("SOME ACTION BUTTON")
                    color: "white"
                    leftPadding: 20
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
            }
        }

        model: ListModel {
            id: listModel
            ListElement { text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
            ListElement { text: "Curabitur sit amet risus" }
            ListElement { text: "Suspendisse vehicula nisi" }
            ListElement { text: "Mauris imperdiet libero" }
            ListElement { text: "Sed vitae dui aliquet augue" }
            ListElement { text: "Praesent in elit eu nulla" }
            ListElement { text: "Etiam vitae magna" }
            ListElement { text: "Pellentesque eget elit euismod" }
            ListElement { text: "Nulla at enim porta" }
            ListElement { text: "Fusce tincidunt odio" }
            ListElement { text: "Ut non ex a ligula molestie" }
            ListElement { text: "Nam vitae justo scelerisque" }
            ListElement { text: "Vestibulum pulvinar tellus" }
            ListElement { text: "Quisque dignissim leo sed gravida" }
        }


        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
    }
}
```

[`ButtonGroup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-buttongroup.html) ensures that only one "button" ([`SwipeDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipedelegate.html) is derived from `AbstractButton`) can be checked at a time. `SwipeDelegate` has no visual effects to represent the checked state, so we can safely use it to keep track of which one should be open. We still need to close the previously open delegate though, so that's where the

```
onCheckedChanged: if (!checked) swipe.close()
```

comes in.

[image: swipedelegate]

Comment: you could also do `checked: swipe.position !== 0` if you want to close the current one as soon as another one is dragged

Comment: @GrecKo your solution is not working, when item #1 start to open, item #2 should start to close so the position of both items changing simultaneously and it cause some kind of unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @Elsiete interesting, I did a quick test and it seamed to work but it maybe not very robust. Maybe change it for `pressed && swipe.position !== 0 || swipe.complete`, the position check could event be removed.

Comment: @GrecKo yup, now it works like a charm. the funny thing is that i tried `pressed && swipe.position !== 0` and didn't figure out why it's not working, but as soon as i see your comment everything becomes clear, thanks.

Comment: for anyone who concerns, if you are using the `ButtonGroup` trick and want to remove an item from the list, make sure to remove the item from `ButtonGroup` too otherwise you'll face a SIGSEGV.

Comment: @Elsiete: Damn... you shouldn't need to do that, but good to know. You can follow this report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63470

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer with the ButtonGroup, here's my solution which does not require to modify the delegates:

SwipeDelegateGroup.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Item {
    id: swipeGroup

    property ListView listView: parent
    QtObject {
        id: d
        property var delegates: swipeGroup.listView.contentItem.children
        property var delegateCache: []

        onDelegatesChanged: {
            for (var i = 0; i < d.delegates.length; i++) {
                var thisItem = d.delegates[i];
                if (!thisItem.hasOwnProperty("swipe")) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (d.delegateCache.indexOf(thisItem) < 0) {
                    d.delegateCache.push(thisItem);

                    thisItem.Component.destruction.connect(function() {
                        d.delegateCache.splice(d.delegateCache.indexOf(thisItem), 1)
                    })

                    thisItem.swipe.opened.connect(function() {
                        for (var j = 0; j < d.delegates.length; j++) {
                            var otherItem = d.delegates[j];
                            if (thisItem === otherItem) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            if (!otherItem.hasOwnProperty("swipe")) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            otherItem.swipe.close();
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just put this into the ListView like this:

```
ListView {

    SwipeDelegateGroup {}

    delegate: SwipeDelegate {
        ...
    }
}
```